# Add .png img to td elements in a dynamically created table in index.ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have just created a table with help from embedded javascript. with help from messerbill I have come up with this:

```
<table id="Table1">   
<tr>
    <th>Kickoff</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>League</th>
    <th>HomeTeam</th>
    <th>AwayTeam</th>
</tr>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { %>
    <% var fileName = result[i].country + ".png" %>     

    <tr>
        <td><%= result[i].Kickoff %> </td>
        <td><%= result[i].statustype %> </td>
        <td><img src="images/flags/<%= fileName %>" alt="images/flags/NoFlag.png" style="width:25px;height:15px;"/> <%= result[i].country %></td>
        <td><%= result[i].league %> </td>
        <td><%= result[i].hteam %> </td>
        <td><%= result[i].ateam %> </td>
    </tr>

<% }; %>
```

This works., However I need some sort of error handler when no png file is found.
Messerbill suggested yesterday to do something like this:

```
<% var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + flags + "\\" + fileName %>
```

but this returns errors. Any suggestions as to how I could get a error handler working.

I would be interested to have it return from public/images/flags/noimg.png when no png file is found on search word.

Any help would be much appreciated

Update:

As an option I thought maybe I would try to search for the icon in the node app like so, :

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var arrayLength = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var imgfile = arr[i].country
    if (fs.exists('../public/images/flags/' + imgfile + ".png") == true) {        
      //console.log('/public/images/flags/' + imgfile + ".png"); 
      console.log('fs exists');       
    } else {
      console.log('Not Found!');   
    }              
  }
```

but here I get some error as im not able to locate a single icon.

frederik :)

Answer (score 1):

just add the image tag to your loop:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= result[i].Kickoff %> </td>
        <td><%= result[i].statustype %> </td>
        <td><%= result[i].country %> <img src="/public/images/<%= result[i].country %>.png" alt="img" /> </td>
        <td><%= result[i].league %> </td>
        <td><%= result[i].hteam %> </td>
        <td><%= result[i].ateam %> </td>
    </tr>
<% }; %>
```

Comment: Hi that looked quite easy. I thought I would need some js code.  just a quick follow up question:  the images are located in public/images/Flags. How could this be updated to point to that direction. And also I would need it to point a default picture when img file is not found, as well as set img width/height

Comment: I tested you suggestion but looks like this adds another Col for the img , I thought I should place it in the same col as "Country"

Comment: this is great stuff , I would need some error handling when no .img is found.

Comment: @Frederik84 the `alt` value will be displayed when no image has been found

Comment: that was what I thought, but look at the server page , I guess I must have some syntax error

Comment: @Frederik84 `http://178.62.253.206:3001/images/flags/International%20Tournaments.png` - as you can see this is not the name of a country. Server is sendinge `International Tournaments` here

Comment: you need to ensure that the file names do really exist - otherwise this can't be prevented

Comment: yes thats is correct , thats why I wanted to display images/flags/NoFlag.png here , but not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: you need to write a method which evaluates if this is a country or not and which builds the image path afterwards

Comment: hmmmm , yeah looks like it needs to be script anyway , just a bit usure how to set it up.. was so close with this route :/

Comment: find out the logic of "which strings are NO valid countries" and i may help you writing that method

Comment: There really is no logic behind this as this depends on the source. Would it not be possible to check the flags directory if the file is present , then if not display noflag.png from the same directory ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166204/discussion-between-messerbill-and-frederik-84).